# Ubuntu 14.04: Cannot change screen resolution

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, resolution, hdmi

I know there are many questions with the same topic, but no solution seem to apply to my case...
I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 on a Toshiba Satellite L735 laptop. My xrandr output is:

```
 Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2390 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192

 VGA-0 connected 1024x768+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
    1024x768       60.0*+
    1360x768       60.0     59.8  
    1152x864       60.0  
    800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
    680x384        60.0     59.8  
    640x480        59.9  
    512x384        60.0  
    400x300        72.2  
    320x240        60.1  

 LVDS-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 166mm
    1366x768       60.0*+

 HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Why don't I have more options for LVDS-0?

I don't seem to be able to Mirror the displays either...

[image: mirror]

I am using the recommended nvidia driver:

[image: nvidia]

**NOTE**

It is not a problem with the second screen, but with Ubuntu/Nvidia themselves... because when I am not connected to a second screen, I still cannot change the resolution.

[image]

Please help! I need to be able to:

1- Change the resolution on the laptop screen (with or without a second screen associated)

2- Use mirror displays when a second screen is present

Comment: Please help, I have tried all the possible solutions in similar threads and nothing...

Comment: Were you able to solve this using NVIDIA drivers. I don't want to go back to x.org server drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1: Disable Unknown Display

Click the Unknown Display Box and below it's on, turn it Off and Apply, Every time you Install Ubuntu for the first Time the Cause is Unknown Display.

## Method 2: Changing Display Driver to X.Org

If you encountering Problems but the First Method doesn't Work, Try this Method

Open **System Settings**

once opened you will see some options, Click **Software & Updates**

and then **Additional Drivers** Section. Tick the **"Using X.Org X Server"** and **Apply Changes** Once applied Reboot. and Try changing the Resolution.

## My Experience

I'm Having Problem with the brightness when NVIDIA Driver is in Use and when trying to Enter a Command for a Solution and rebooted the Brightness is remain the same,So i try changing to X.Org and it Worked!

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem, cause when I am not connected to a second screen, I still cannot change the resolution...

Comment: Did you attempt to try 860 x 600? btw My laptop can change Resolution, The box shown in my laptop is Pink

Comment: DaniCee i Provided Another Method i assume it works! :)